# How to use multiple UITableView in single view Controller in iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am new to iOS development. Currently,  I am working on a project in which I use more than two `UITableView`s in a single view controller, but both data sources come from server one by one. When the first api hit, it shows the result, but after select item from that list I am unable to show the response in list.

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("sdfsdfsf")
    var count:Int?
    if tableView == self.pat_search_listview {
        count = serach_data.count
    }
    else  if tableView == self.visit_listview {
        count = all_vist_data.count
    }
    return count!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    if tableView == self.pat_search_listview {
        cell.textLabel?.text = serach_data[indexPath.row].name + "     " + serach_data[indexPath.row].id
    }
        
        
    else  if tableView == self.visit_listview {
        print("second listview")
        cell.textLabel?.text = all_vist_data[indexPath.row].date
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: it is correct. what issues faced in this code ?

Comment: Which one of the tableViews you see on the screen?

Comment: issue is that it show nothing in second uitableview

Comment: ite dose not show anything

Comment: @PardeepKumar is this line `print("second listview")` executed?

Comment: Does data source for second table view contains data to show?

Comment: nothing printed

Comment: show your didselect method

Comment: i alse implement delegate and datasource method

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.serach_pat_listview_view.isHidden = true
        
        let all_visit_api = apis.Get_Dos(pat_id: serach_data[indexPath.row].id)
        
        hit_chart_note_api(api: all_visit_api)

    }

Comment: Check server response for second data source and confirm you get correct data.

Comment: i got the server response it prints in logs

Comment: are u showing both tableview at the same time , If yes remove else if  and replace with if condition.

Comment: after didselet method i rhide the tablview and then i want to show the next tableview

Comment: is tableview reloadData called for second tableview ?

Comment: Also recheck if outlet, delegate and datasource is set for second tableview

Comment: You have to check your tableView outlet which is connected properly with respective objects. and In other way, You can also connect both table view with the single outlet but make sure you have set different tag value for different table.

Answer (score 0):

check the Outlet connections for both tableViews... both shouldn't be nil in viewDidLoad

in viewDidLoad:

```
self.pat_search_listview.dataSource = self; 
self.visit_listview = self;

self.pat_search_listview.tag = 0
self.visit_listview.tag = 1
```

in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

if tableView.tag == 0
...
else
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to set delegate and data source and don't forget to reload the table after adding/updating the arrays.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if tableView == self.pat_search_listview
    {
        return serach_data.count/*pat_search_listview's Array count*/
    }
    else  if tableView == self.visit_listview
    {
        return all_vist_data.count/*visit_listview Array count*/
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    if tableView == self.pat_search_listview
    {
        cell.textLabel?.text = serach_data[indexPath.row].name + "     " + serach_data[indexPath.row].id
    }
    else  if tableView == self.visit_listview
    {
        print("second listview")
        cell.textLabel?.text = all_vist_data[indexPath.row].date
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if tableView == self.pat_search_listview
    {
        //--- Item at index from pat_search_listview
    }
    else  if tableView == self.visit_listview
    {
        print("second listview")
        //--- Item at index from visit_listview
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all, for giving me your support or ideas